# to be heralded by someone

Tags: meaning

What does 'to herald' mean in the following passage from the [Guardian](http://www.theguardian.com/tv-and-radio/2015/sep/28/smithers-mr-burns-assistant-simpsons-gay).

> Patty came out and expressed her desire to get married to a woman in a
>   February 2005 episode that was criticized by conservative media
>   monitoring groups such as the American Family Association and
>   **heralded** by LGBT rights groups such as GLAAD.

If it means

> to say publicly that someone or something will be good or important  ,
>   be heralded as something 
>   http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/herald_1

can it be used without the part  "as something" ?

Could you give me a few synonym that we can replace the word herald with in this sense?

Comment: I think you've answered your own question. It has come to mean what you say it means (an antonym of 'criticize', when talking about something new), and it is regularly used as the Guardian has. I'm sure you can find some synonyms yourself, but *'praised'* springs to mind straight away.

Comment: You say, "**If** it means..."  Can you instead say where this definition came from. Also you appear to  cut the definition short. Does the original really end with the words "as something"?

Comment: @Rathony - I think you are confusing the verb 'to herald' with the verb 'to headline'.

Comment: @chaslyfromUK  the definition is from Longman Dictionaries and I edited the question

Comment: @Amanda - Thanks for adding the link. The phrase 'be heralded as something' cannot be part of the definition. Otherwise you would be using the word 'herald' to define the word 'herald' - a circular definition.  I presume the phrase in blue is a heading for the subsequent example.  So the answer is, yes, you can can omit that phrase.

Answer (score 2):

According to Merriam-Webster, *herald* can mean basically 4 things as a transitive verb.

**Herald**, transitive verb ([Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/herald)):

> 1. to give notice of :  announce
> 2. to greet especially with enthusiasm :  **hail**
> 3. to publicize
> 4. to signal the approach of :  foreshadow

**Hail** has a very similar meaning as suggested by the dictionary ([MW](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/hail)):

> 1. salute, greet
> 2. **to greet with enthusiastic approval :  acclaim**

So **welcome** or **greet with enthusiasm** will do, too.

**Greet** ([MW](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/greet)):

> to respond to in a certain way.
>
> **Audience members greeted the speech with boos.**

Comment: Hey! Look, details and citations! +1

Comment: It is. And don't worry about yesterday. Here, lemme show you a few formatting tricks. If you don't like the effect, please feel free to roll the changes back.